# "webpack" vs "webpack --watch" creates different output

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Im using this set up as the base of my project: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

When I run `webpack`, it compiles a bundle that works in the browser.

When I run `webpack --watch`, it re-compiles on file change, but causes this error in the browser:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

I looked at the output of both, and it looks like `webpack --watch` **does not include the webpack bootstrap code or my modules - only the entry file transpiled**.

`webpack`

- Includes all of my modules in a single file, along with using webpacks own module require.
- E.g: `var io = __webpack_require__(20);`

`webpack --watch`

- Only includes my entry module - *no other modules, no `__webpack_require__`*.
- E.g. `var io = require("socket.io-client");`

Versions:
 - webpack: 3.7.1
 - tsc: 1.8.10

```
module.exports = {
entry: "./src/index.tsx",
output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist"
},

// Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
devtool: "source-map",

resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
},

module: {
    rules: [
        // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

        // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
        { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
    ]
},

// When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
// assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
// This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
// dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to remove `outDir` from `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/"
}
}
```

It was the tsconfig.json file having a conflicting output directory. Files are only written by typescript when using `webpack --watch`